# How do I update nuget.exe version used by dotnet cli

Tags: .net-core, nuget, asp.net-core-cli

I have installed the dotnet core sdk and it all works. I want to update the nuget version though so that when I run `dotnet pack` it uses the latest nuget. With normal nuget.exe I can run `nuget.exe update -self` and it updates itself. However with dotnet cli there doesnt seem to be any equivalent command. I also cant find which nuget.exe path its referencing to update it there manually.

Any ideas on where its located or how to update this? Or do I need to just update the entire .net core SDK to get a newer nuget version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am pretty sure you can't upgrade the nuget version shipped in .NET Core. It's a core part of the .NET Core SDK and no individual component of SDK can be upgraded.

Why do you want to use a newer NuGet version?

Comment: Well initialliy I wanted a specific feature only available from a specific version which is why I was going to update. Then I realised that it was on a new enough version and then was just curious to know if it was possible or not. The feature I wanted was https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/package-versioning#version-ranges-and-wildcards this though

Comment: Looking further at this article though I assume you're right. It lists nuget 4.3 on a seperate point than dotnet.exe v2.0. So I guess everything from dotnet.exe is packed together and I'd have to update the whole thing to get a newer version. Pretty sucky, but whatever

Comment: @DavidEsteves - The SDKs can be installed side-by-side. You can use a [`global.json` file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/global-json) in your solution directory to specify to use an earlier version of the SDK than the latest you have installed, if necessary.

Comment: Good point. You can't change an SDK (like upgrade the nuget version), but you can install multiple SDKs side-by-side.